# Dynamically increasing the number of elements in a listview

Tags: android, android-listview, dynamic-data

I want to increase the number of items my list view will display dynamically when the list view is scrolled to the end.
In my case my listview will display 10 items initially. then when we scroll to the last item it must start displaying 10 more items and so on.
how can i do that??

Here is my custom array adapter

```
    package com.android.listview;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.android.listview.R;
import com.android.listview.Product;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.listview.ListViewActivity;

public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> implements
        OnScrollListener {

    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Product> values;

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView text;
        public ImageView image;
    }

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            ArrayList<Product> arg3) {
        super(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
        this.context = arg0;
        this.values = arg3;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        int product_id = 0;
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_items, parent, false);
        try {

            ImageView wic_logo = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
            TextView label = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);

            Product p = values.get(position);
            product_id = p.productId;
            String date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy")
                    .format(new java.util.Date(p.timeStamp));
            label.setText(p.productName + "\n" + p.reportedPrice + "   MRP: "
                    + p.mrp + "\n" + "Discount: " + p.discount + "%   "
                    + p.area + "  " + p.city + "\n" + "Shared by " + p.userName
                    + " " + "on" + " " + date);

            wic_logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.wic_logo_small);
            Log.d("date", "" + date);

            Log.d("Custom Array Adapter", "at" + position);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Custom Array Adapter", "catch");
        }

        return rowView;
    }

    public void onScroll(AbsListView arg0, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        Log.d("entered onScroll", " " + firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount
                + totalItemCount);
        if (((firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) >= totalItemCount - 1)) {
            Log.d("entered if", " " + firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount
                    + totalItemCount);
            // if we're at the bottom of the listview, load more data
            addData(totalItemCount, values.get(totalItemCount).productId);
        }
    }

    private void addData(int totalItemCount, int productId) {

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "last item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView arg0, int arg1) {

    }
}
```

and here is my activity

```
package com.android.listview;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.android.listview.CustomArrayAdapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ListViewActivity extends Activity {

    static Product[] feed_products_list;
    private JSONArray JArray;
    private InputStream is;
    private StringBuilder sb;
    private String result;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button feed_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.feedButton_feed);
        feed_button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grey);
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/wic2/mobile/feed");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
                String line = "0";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
                Log.d("result", result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("error", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
            }

            Log.e("response", "response is:" + response.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
        }

        ListView tv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.feedListView);
        try {
            Log.d("JArray", "entered try");
            JArray = new JSONArray(result);
            int length = JArray.length();
            feed_products_list = new Product[length+1];
            Log.d("JArray", "try last line");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("JArray", "in catch");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JSONObject jsonObj;

        for (int i = 0; i < JArray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                Log.d("jsonObj", "entered try");
                jsonObj = JArray.getJSONObject(i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("jsonObj", "in catch");
                continue;
            }

            try {
                Log.d("feed_products_list", "entered try");
                feed_products_list[i] = new Product(jsonObj.getInt("id"),
                        jsonObj.getString("image"),
                        jsonObj.getString("product_name"),
                        jsonObj.getString("reported_price_formated"),
                        jsonObj.getString("store_area"),
                        jsonObj.getString("store_city"),
                        jsonObj.getString("mrp"),
                        jsonObj.getString("user_name"),
                        jsonObj.getLong("reported_timestamp"),
                        jsonObj.getInt("discount"));
                Log.d("feed_products_list", feed_products_list[i].productName);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("feed_products_list in catch",
                        feed_products_list[i].productName);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        tv.setAdapter(new CustomArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.feed_items,
                R.id.label, feed_products_list));


    }
}
```

and one more problem is that i have to initialize my array feed_products_list[length] with the number of items in the JArray. so i cannot change array size every time i scroll to the last item and re-populate the whole list again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there's a few problems with your code. In your `Activity`, change your variable `values` to an `ArrayList<Product>` since you cannot manipulate the length of an array after creation. Next, rename JArray to jArray; if the first letter is a capital that should indicate you're dealing with a class instead of a variable.

Also, you're not using the ViewHolder pattern, which greatly improves performance. Check out [this link on vogella.com about ListView](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html); more specifically, *check out chapters 3.1 and 3.2*.

In `CustomArrayAdapter`, implement `OnScrollListener` and add the required methods. Then, in `onScroll(...)`, determine if you want to add data (e.g. user reached bottom of list). Finally, load the new items, add them to your dataset with `values.add(product)` or `values.addAll(products)` where products is a `List` of `Product`s, and call `notifyDataSetChanged` from within your `CustomArrayAdapter` after every call to `values.add(...)` or `values.addAll(...)`.

For example, you could change the following in your code:

In your **Activity**:

- Remove the lines

  ```
  int length = JArray.length();
  feed_products_list = new Product[length+1];
  ```
- Remove the 'static' from your `feed_products_list` and change it to an ArrayList:

  ```
  private ArrayList<Product> feed_products_list = new ArrayList<Product>();
  ```
- Instead of `feed_products_list[i] = new Product(jsonObj.getInt("id"), .... yadiya ...`, call feed_products_list.add(new Product(jsonObj.getInt("id"), ... yadiya ...`.

In your **Adapter**:

- Make the class `implement OnScrollListener`, and set the `onScroll()`-method to something like the following:

  ```
  public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                          int visibleItemCount, final int totalItemCount) {
      if(((firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) >= totalItemCount)) {

          // if we're at the bottom of the listview, load more data
          addData(totalItemCount);
      }
  }
  ```
- Create a method `addData(long offset)`:

  ```
  private void addData(long offset) {

      // download your data, pass the offset so you know where to start
      // and when you convert your json into `Product`s
      Product product = new Product(JSONObject.getInt("id"), ... yadiya ...);
      this.add(product);
      this.notifyDataSetChanged();

      // make sure to call notifyDataSetChanged() on your UI-Thread.
  }
  ```

Comment: here the offset is the position of the last item int he list from where we want to add additional items??

Comment: Yes, you can use this to signal your server what items have already been downloaded. Other ways are by posting the current datetime, or the datetime of the last-fetched item - it depends on your needs.

Comment: where is it specified that the onScroll method is called when i scroll the listview i am using.....just before the if block in onScroll i added a log and that never appeared in my log cat when i scrolled the list

Comment: Does your class `implement onScrollListener(...)`?

Comment: u mean my CustomArrayAdapter class??...yes

Comment: In your `Activity`, instead of  `tv.setAdapter(new CustomArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.feed_items,
                R.id.label, feed_products_list));`, do `CustomArrayAdapter mAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(....); tv.setAdapter(mAdapter); mAdapter.setOnScrollListener(mAdapter);`. That should fix it.

Comment: The method setOnScrollListener(CustomArrayAdapter) is undefined for the type CustomArrayAdapter

Comment: shud i add setOnScrollListener in CustomArrayAdapter class....and keep the onScroll code in it?....instead of implementing OnScrollListener and implementing unimplemented onScroll n onScrollStateChanged?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `tv.setOnScrollListener(mAdapter)`. Btw, naming your listview 'tv' is really confusing. Wouldn't it be easier to name it `ListView listview = ..` or `ListView lv = ...`? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

For dynamically increasing the size, it is better to use ArrayList.For scrolling you can use @Mayank idea.

Answer (score 1):

you should attach a `scroll listener` to your `listview`

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view); 
lv.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,  
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) { 
        //Check if the last view is visible 
        if (view.getLastVisiblePosition()+1 == 10) { 
            //load more content 
        } 
    } 
});
```

**Update**

so initially in your `feed_products_list` you'll have 10 items, when user scrolls down, add 10 more items to the list and reset the `CustomArrayAdapter` to `listView`. Keep doing that untill you have all the items in the list.

Comment: thank you. But also please help me how to dynamically increase my array size which holds the list items. initially it was 10 when scrolled it must me 20 30 40 n so on

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do this. Android listviews can easily handle thousands entries - provided that you write your adapter carefully, and reuse  views. So in your getView() method you have to check whether converView is supplied and of correct , and then just populate it with new values. (Andriod is so smart, that it offers to recycle list entries which are n ot visible right now) - this will give you immediate performance boost

Do it like this:

```
View rowView = convertView;
if(rowView == null) {
   // do what you are doing now to inflate view
}
// do what you are doing now to set up view

return rowView;
```

Increasing size of list would make sense if you do not like to load all the entries from 
whatever storage you immediately - in this case you have to register scroll listener and react to it  by loading missing entries, and  then signaling that list data changed.  And you do not have to use array as backing storage - list will be perfect match for this purpose

Comment: could you please provide with a link which elaborated your explanation about converView in the 1st para

Comment: @Archie.bpgc is downloading content from a websource; loading more data from the start might be detrimental to the user experience as it takes longer to load initially, especially if the connection is bad or the size of the data-collection is large.

Comment: I do almost same thing in my games.   Initially I load all highscore data in background, so noew user does not have all the highscores on start ( and usually new user is not interested on them before he plazed couple of games )  - so highscores are loaded in backgorund. After this I pull just changes since last known higscore entry (small).  My data live somewhere in a unrelated object, and list adapter just pulls list fo them when it needs it.

Comment: Yes, that's fine in situations where the user doesn't need the data as soon as possible, or if the dataset is not that large to begin with. In other cases it can be important not to keep the user waiting, especially if you have the option of loading more when it's needed. Also, you might save a lot of data if you've got a large userbase by loading it on-demand.

Answer (score 0):

use ArrayList instead of array 
like this

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Product> values;
```

and in your `getView()`

```
            Product p = values.get(position);
```

you could provide a method inside your adapter to add element to the ArrayList and `notifyDataSetChange()` it looks like this

```
public void addElement(Product p){
values.add(p);
notifiyDataSetChange();
}
```

use the `OnScrollListener` to load more data 
example :

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,  
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) { 

        if (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount <= firstVisibeItem + 5) { 
            //load more content 

            .....
            adpater.addElement(p);

        } 


     } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like [Lazy loading](https://github.com/desertjim/LazyLoadingGridView).

It is Called as Lazy Loading. i am sure you haven't Tried searching like that. And i have given you example of GridView. This is other link of Listview [Other Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)