# How to show huge data (50,000 records) in listview in android

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

we have a server i am getting response in JSON format and i have a customized listview  where each row showing 4-5 texts now i want my application to show list as it is loading data from response and reflect in listview i have used async task for it code is below but it is reflecting data after getting all the data i want it to display as soon as it is responding  :

```
class UpdateLoadingAirport extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> 
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String page=params[0];
           System.out.println("Pageno====================>asynctask for loading first is :"+page);
            String url="http://xyz/"+page;  


        //  String urlToSend="http://182.72.123.138:9502/AirportWebService.asmx/Get50Airports?page=";
            try {


                HttpGet post=new HttpGet(url);
                HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
                org.apache.http.HttpResponse response=client.execute(post);

                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode == 200)
                {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));

                    System.out.println("<-----------------------Registration Success------------------------>");

                    String line;
                    StringBuilder  stringBuilder= new StringBuilder();
                    while ((line = reader.readLine())!=null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line);
                    }
                    reader.close();
                    content.close();
                    resultOf= stringBuilder.toString();
                    //saveAirportFBO(resultOf);

                    //System.out.println("Result of url :"+resultOf);
                    //parsedString=getJSONStringFormat(resultOf);

                     JSONObject updatedAirportJSONObject;
                    try {
                        updatedAirportJSONObject = new JSONObject(resultOf);
                        JSONArray updatedAirportJSONArray1;

                        updatedAirportJSONArray1 = updatedAirportJSONObject.getJSONArray("Airports");
                        noOfPages=updatedAirportJSONObject.getString("TotalPages");
                        System.out.println("no of pages:===========>"+noOfPages);
                        for(int l=0;l<updatedAirportJSONArray1.length();l++)
                        {
                            JSONObject tempJSONObject=updatedAirportJSONArray1.getJSONObject(l);
                            airportCode =tempJSONObject.getString("AirportCode");
                            airportName =tempJSONObject.getString("Name");
                            AirportModel airportModel=new AirportModel(airportCode,airportName);
                            airportArrayList.add(airportModel);



                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        CustomListViewAdapter adapter1 = new CustomListViewAdapter(SearchAirportActivity.this,R.layout.airport_singlerow,airportArrayList);

        airportListView.setAdapter(adapter1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether I get you right, but you maybe should look into publishProgress and onProgressUpdate (in AsyncTask) in order to update your list after each item and not after all entries are processed...?

Comment: The best way to show 50,000 results is not to show 50,000 unless you *absolutely* need to. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080811/android-endless-list

Answer (score 2):

I would go for increasing the List size dynamically. Load more items when user reaches to end of the List. as @RGraham suggested.

[Android Endless List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080811/android-endless-list)

[Dynamically increasing the number of elements in a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152236/dynamically-increasing-the-number-of-elements-in-a-listview)