# Listing large amount of data in listview

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

I want to three things :

1.Want to show 50000 contacts from db
2.Fast scroller implementation
3.Filter implementation (Edittext)

Currently what i'm doing is :

1. I Listed contacts in list view by pulling data in worker thread(using aynctask). But in single query itself I'm pulling 50000 contacts. That takes some time and sometimes facing Out-of-memory exception.
2. I used list-view indexer  for fast scroller
3. using Gauva library for filtering

Please suggest some efficient way to achieve this. Anyway user is not going to see 10000 immediately but i need to implement fast scroller that  why pulling all data

Comment: first for 50000 list use pagination that fetch 50 record at a time. and use Recyclerview not listview. and for filter use default arrylist method, there is no need for any library

Comment: Thanks for immediate reply.But I need have Fastscroller that why showing all data and with out gauva its taking more time that why i used gauva.

Comment: Is it possible to show fastscroller with pagination.

Comment: yes sqlite @pskink

Answer (score 1):

You may need to increase the list size dynamically...Refer the below answers

[Android Endless List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080811/android-endless-list)

[Dynamically increasing the number of elements in a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152236/dynamically-increasing-the-number-of-elements-in-a-listview)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is it possible to add  fastscroller functionality with pagination